# Prove by Induction that $n! > \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$ for $n>1$

Tags: induction

I'm studying a combinatorics text ([Cameron](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521457610)) in preparation for taking discrete math this upcoming semester. I've taken a fair amount of math in college, through Calculus II, but this is my first 500+ level math course.

Here is the problem that I'm stuck on. It appears after an introduction to Induction proofs.

Prove by Induction that:

$$n! > \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$

for $n>1$.

The book gives a hint: may use the fact that $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n < e$ for all n.

I have the base step:

$$P(1): 1! > \left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^1$$
$$1 > 0.37$$

For the inductive step, assume:

$$P(k): k! > \left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k$$

and prove:

$$(k + 1)! > \left(\frac{k+1}{e}\right)^{k + 1}$$

Comment: I've tried manipulating the expression around in several different ways. I noticed that $k^{k+1} = k^{k}k$.

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out how to use $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n < e$ for all n, seems like this could be key.

Comment: It is key, good job for noticing that :D

Comment: To be proven: $$(k+1)\left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k> \left(\frac{k+1}{e}\right)^{k + 1}$$
Indeed this is *equivalent* to: $$\left(\frac{k+1}k\right)^k<e$$
Maybe note this is: $$\frac1{k+1}\frac{(k+1)^{k+1}}{k^k}<\frac{e^{k+1}}{e^k}$$

Comment: Now use your hint!

Comment: @DougM Haha, you are a little late to the party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$(k+1)!=(k+1)k!>(k+1)\left(\frac ke\right)^k>\frac{k+1}e\left(\frac{k+1}e\right)^k=\left(\frac{k+1}e\right)^{k+1}$$

The last inequality step uses the fact that

$$k^k>\frac{(k+1)^k}e$$

or,

$$e>\frac{(k+1)^k}{k^k}=\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k$$

Comment: Using the transitive property was something that I didn't think of, very helpful.

Comment: @JoeD. Well, glad to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**.  Start be re-expressing the right hand side for $k+1$ to get
$$\Bigl(\frac{k+1}{e}\Bigr)^{k+1}
  =\frac{k+1}{e}\Bigl(\frac{k+1}{k}\Bigr)^k\Bigl(\frac ke\Bigr)^k
  =\frac{k+1}{e}\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{k}\Bigr)^k\Bigl(\frac ke\Bigr)^k\ .$$
Now use the hint you were given, and the inductive assumption.

Comment: How did you arrive at that? Not sure how this was done....

Comment: Suggestion: for an induction proof, the first thing to think of is: how do I connect the statement for $k+1$ with the statement for $k$?  In this case I looked at the right hand sides, ignoring the $e$ factors (details can be sorted out once we have the main idea).  So I am looking at$$(k+1)^{k+1}\quad\hbox{and}\quad k^k\ ;$$remembering what we are given in the hint,$$(k+1)^{k+1}=(k+1)(k+1)^k=(k+1)\Bigl(\frac{k+1}k\Bigr)^kk^k$$looks like a promising start.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $$\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{k+1}{e}\right)^{k+1}}{\left(\dfrac{k}{e}\right)^{k}}=\dfrac{k+1}{e}\left(\dfrac{k+1}{k}\right)^k=\dfrac{k+1}{e}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{k}\right)^k$$ while 
$$\dfrac{(k+1)!}{k!}=k+1$$

Answer (score 1):

For the proof by induction, assume that 
$$k!>\left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k$$
and show that this implies
$$(k+1)!>\left(\frac{k+1}{e}\right)^{k+1}$$
you can express this inequality as:
$$(k+1)k!>\left(\frac{k+1}{e}\right)\left(\frac{k+1}{e}\right)^k$$
divide by $(k+1)$:
$$k!>\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)\left(\frac{k+1}{e}\right)^k$$
When this is combined with the initial assumption, it's apparent that proving the following inequality to be true will complete the proof by induction:
$$\left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k>\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)\left(\frac{k+1}{e}\right)^k$$
refactor:
$$\frac{k^k}{e^k}>\frac{(k+1)^k}{e^{k+1}}$$
rearrange:
$$e>\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^k=\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k$$
This last inequality is already given by your hint, so the proof is complete.